# Web Api Caching and "Can't Access Closed Stream"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, caching, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use this caching library for asp.net web api (https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache)

After installing it I got this error and narrowed it down to a class in my `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` class.

```
Cannot access a closed Stream
```

I believe it has to do with the `Task.Factory.StarNew()` or `XmlTextWriter` closing the steam somewhere in the `WriteToStreamAsync` method.  Is there another way to handle this code?

```
 public class CustomXmlFormatter : XmlMediaTypeFormatter 
    {
        public CustomXmlFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
            Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);
        }

        protected UTF8Encoding Encoding { get; set; }

        public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            if (type == null)
                return false;

            return true;
        }
        public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            if (type == null)
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (var xmlr = new XmlTextReader(readStream))
                {
                    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(type);
                    return serializer.ReadObject(xmlr);
                }
            });
        }

        public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(type, "Response", "");

            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (var xmlw = new XmlTextWriter(writeStream, Encoding))
                {
                    xmlw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    serializer.WriteObject(xmlw, value);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the `XmlWriterSettings` that Web API's `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` uses when writing out xml.

```
var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    CloseOutput = false,
    CheckCharacters = false
};
```

The above settings are used like following...you could do similar stuff in your case too.

```
var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writeStream, writerSettings);

serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, value);
```

Just FYI...The above snippets of code were taken from Web API's `XmlMediaTypeFormatter`...you can take a look at it's source code for more ideas...